# Sample size for LASSO

Tags: sample-size, lasso

What considerations should be made regarding sample size for using LASSO or elasticnet? We are going to gather expression data from 1700 genes and our response variable is multinomial (3 categories).

Comment: You might want to add some detail to your question, as I doubt there is enough info here for anyone to be very helpful to you.

Comment: I don't need a specific answer to my problem, just some guidelines regarding sample size when using LASSO.

Comment: The answer you will likely get then is "more is better".

Comment: Well... in your first comment you state I should add some detail to my question. Telling my what details should I add would answer part of my original question.

Comment: What is a gene? How are your expression data likely to be distributed>

Comment: A gene is a DNA sequence containing hereditary information. We are meassuring the level of expression of each gene and, for now, let's consider that expression data follows a lognormal distribution.

Comment: You could also give some expectations for what your model might find (effect sizes, number of retained covaraites, etc.) With more detail, you might be able to develop some simulations to help you make a good guess regarding sample size...but without more info, regardless of the model, the answer is usually "it's depends".